# Unable to drag and drop shadow dom elements using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, puppeteer, shadow-dom

I want to use Puppeteer to perform drag-and-drop operations on Shadow Dom pages like the following.

But this doesn't work.

The console showed the event log for dragstart, but no other event logs.

The dragenter and dragover events don't seem to be firing, but I can't figure out why.

If you know the cause and solution, please let me know.

#### my site

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drag-and-drop test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="shadow"></div>
    <script>
      const el = document.querySelector('#shadow');
      const shadowRoot = el.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
          #drop {
            width: 5em;
            height: 5em;
            border: 1px solid black;
          }
        </style>
        <div id="drag" draggable="true">drag me</div>
        <div id="drop"></div>
      `;
    </script>
    <script>
      window.didDragStart = false;
      window.didDragEnter = false;
      window.didDragOver = false;
      window.didDrop = false;
      const drag = document.getElementById('shadow').shadowRoot.getElementById('drag');
      const drop = document.getElementById('shadow').shadowRoot.getElementById('drop');
      drag.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('id', event.target.id);
        window.didDragStart = true;
      });
      drop.addEventListener('dragenter', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        window.didDragEnter = true;
      });
      drop.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        window.didDragOver = true;
      });
      drop.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        const id = event.dataTransfer.getData('id');
        const el = document.getElementById('shadow').shadowRoot.getElementById(id);
        if (el) {
          event.target.appendChild(el);
          window.didDrop = true;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### my puppeteer code

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("my site");

const destination = await page.$('pierce/#drop');
const destinationBox = await destination.boundingBox();
const dropPosition = {
  x: destinationBox.x
  y: destinationBox.y
};
await page.hover('pierce/#drag');
await this.page.mouse.down();
await this.page.mouse.move(dropPosition.x, dropPosition.y);
await this.page.mouse.up()
```